# Fusion of two tables with Specific SUM operation in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have two views in my database, here are their structures:

Table 1 (Stock product entries) :

```
---------------------------------------
| Date     | Product     | Quantity   |
---------------------------------------
|2013-06-06| Procuct001  | 40         |
---------------------------------------
```

Table 2 (Stock product outputs) :

```
---------------------------------------
| Date     | Product     | Quantity   |
---------------------------------------
|2013-06-07| Procuct001  | 15         |
---------------------------------------
|2013-06-08| Procuct001  | 5          |
---------------------------------------
```

I want to have a third view (or table) where I'll store all the stock's movements (entries or outputs) but I don't want to store the entered or retrieved quantity, but the difference (which means the stock's balance). In our case, the new table should contain :

Table 3 (Stock balance) :

```
---------------------------------------
| Date     | Product     | Quantity   |
---------------------------------------
|2013-06-06| Procuct001  | 40         |
---------------------------------------
|2013-06-07| Procuct001  | 25         |
---------------------------------------
|2013-06-07| Procuct001  | 20         |
---------------------------------------
```

I am using SQL Server 2012 with SP1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option using a Common Table Expression, utilizing `ROW_NUMBER` to seed your list (grouped by product):

```
with cte as (
  select dt, product, quantity, row_number() over (partition by product order by dt) rn
  from (
    select * from t1
    union
    select * from t2
    ) t
  ) 
select c.dt, c.product,
  c2.quantity - coalesce(sum(c3.quantity),0) runningty 
from cte c
  inner join (
    select product, quantity
    from cte
    where rn = 1) c2 on c.product = c2.product
  left join cte c3 on c.product = c3.product and c3.rn <= c.rn and c3.rn <> 1
group by c.dt, c.product, c2.quantity
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/143ce/1)

Depending on your data, you may not need to extra inner join to get your "1st" record -- you could perhaps use something like this instead:

```
with cte as (
  select dt, product, quantity, row_number() over (partition by product order by dt) rn
  from (
    select * from t1
    union
    select * from t2
    ) t
  ) 
select c.dt, c.product,
  max(c.quantity) over (partition by c.product) - coalesce(sum(c3.quantity),0) runningty 
from cte c
  left join cte c3 on c.product = c3.product and c3.rn <= c.rn and c3.rn <> 1
group by c.dt, c.product, c.quantity
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But with more entries it's not working correctly ! See here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a14e6/1

Comment: @walidAndroidLover -- looks correct to me (from my understanding of your question).  What should those results be?  I thought you were trying to group by product.

Comment: Well, in this example : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a14e6/1

We have inserted 40 products then we retrieved 15, then we inserted 10 so basically we should have 35 items remaining in the stock. But the results are giving 15 on 2013-06-08 instead of 35. 
Do you get my question now ? Many thanks

Comment: After one hour of tests and edits, here is the right code to achieve the task. I just had to do a simple 'GROUP BY' at the first step and everything is working now : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/73e79/1

Special thanks to @sgeddes for his precious help.